# A graph with $8$ vertices where $2$ out of any $3$ vertices are adjacent has a minimum of $12$ edges... why?

Tags: graph-theory

Two examples of such graphs with the minimum number of edges are two 4-cliques (each with 6 edges) <s>or a cube</s>.  But why is 12 the minimum?  Can this be proven?

EDIT: now that someone has disproven my cube example (not sure what I was thinking), I suspect it might be that all graphs with $n$ vertices where 2 out of any 3 vertices are adjacent consist of 2 cliques of size $\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ and $\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil$, respectively.  Not sure if that is right, though.

Comment: Do you mean "2 out of any 3 vertices are adjacent..."?

Comment: Yes, sorry - I edited the title

Comment: Well there are 56 ways to choose 3 vertices out of the 8.  And for a given edge, there are 56*3=168 ways to select a group of three and decide which two vertices in that group it will join.  I'm not sure what you mean, however.

Comment: A cube does have 3 vertices in which none are adjacent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If every vertex has at least $3$ incident edges, then that makes $24$ incident (vertex,edge) pairs. Since each edge contributes only $2$ such pairs, we have at least $12$ edges, as required.

So suppose, from now on, that some vertex $P$ doesn't have at least $3$ incident edges. If $P$ has only one incident edge or none, then there are $6$ or more vertices not adjacent to $P$. Every two of these $6$ must be adjacent, because any two that are not adjacent would, when combined with $P$, constitute three vertices with no adjacency. So the number of edges would be at least $\binom62=15$, which is more than enough.

There remains the case that $P$ has exactly two incident edges, say $PQ$ and $PR$. Among the $5$ vertices other than $P,Q,R$, every two must be adjacent, lest they and $P$ form three points with no adjacencies. So that gives us $\binom52=10$ edges among those $5$ vertices. Together with the edges $PQ$ and $PR$, we have $12$, as required.